# UILocalNotification fire when i open the notification tray to see the notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i used the local notification and schedule the fire date but when the app is in background and  i open the notification tray to see the notification then the local notification is fire automatically but the fire date is remaining..is there any solution to solve that problem

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have two issues. First, the local notification has been created with a fire date set in the past - that's why its appearing as soon as you open the app.

Secondly, you may be setting the notification's repeatInterval to a non-zero value, which will cause it to come up more than once.

See the below code for setting a local notification to fire at 3pm:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.alertBody = @"This is a test alert";
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setHour: 15];
[comps setMinute: 0];
[comps setSecond: 0];
NSDate *threePM = [currentCalendar dateFromComponents:comps];

// Test if the current time is after three or not:
if(threePM != [threePM earlierDate: [NSDate date]])
{
  comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
  [comps setDay: 1];
  threePM = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: threePM options: 0];
}

localNotification.fireDate = threePM;
localNotification.repeatInterval = 0;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: localNotification];
```